# DataFrame からタイムゾーンを削除したいがうまくいかない

Tags: python, python3, pandas

以下の DataFrame があります。

```
　　　　install_t
0                                   NaT
1      2020-03-28 19:31:22.159174+09:00
2                                   NaT
3      2019-12-31 10:38:38.165566+09:00
4      2020-06-14 15:29:41.511317+09:00
Name: install_t, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(540)]
```

上記の install_t 列を `2019-12-31` という日付のみにしたいので、以下のコードを書いたのですが、エラーも出ず、結果に変化もありません。
なぜでしょうか。宜しくお願いします。

```py
df['install_t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['install_t']) 
df['install_t'] = df['install_t'].dt.round("D")
df['install_t']
```

またタイムゾーンを削除できないかと以下も試みましたが、エラーがでました。
助けてください。

```py
df6['install_t'] = df6['install_t'].replace(tzinfo=None)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-e26e2db5d810> in <module>
----> 1 df6['install_t'] = df6['install_t'].replace(tzinfo=None)

TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'
```

Answer (score 1):

この記事が適用できると思われます。
[How to remove timezone from a Timestamp column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49198068/9014308)

> You can use `tz_localize` to change the time zone, a naive timestamp corresponds to time zone `None`:
> `tz_localize`を使用してタイムゾーンを変更できます。単純なタイムスタンプはタイムゾーン`None`に対応します：

> ```
> testdata['time'].dt.tz_localize(None)
> ```

> Unless the column is an index you have to call method `dt` to access pandas datetime functions.
> 列がインデックスでない限り、pandasの日時関数にアクセスするには、メソッド `dt`を呼び出す必要があります。

---

質問内容に適用すれば、以下になるでしょう。

```
df['install_t'] = df['install_t'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。